# How to test a Web Service with Watin

Tags: .net, nunit, watin

I'm trying to write a test that invokes a web service and tests it's results.

```
[Test]
        public void should_display_correct_customer_when_DoCustomerSearch_is_invoked()
        {
            using (var browser = new IE("http://localhost:61245/WebServices/CustomerSearch.asmx?op=DoCustomerSearch"))
            {       
                browser.WaitForComplete();

                browser.TextField(Find.ByName("txtSearch")).TypeText("microsoft");
                browser.Button(Find.ByValue("Invoke")).Click();
                browser.Close();

                IE poppedUpBrowser = IE.AttachTo<IE>(Find.ByUrl("http://localhost:61245/WebServices/CustomerSearch.asmx/DoCustomerSearch"));

                poppedUpBrowser.WaitForComplete();
                Assert.IsTrue(poppedUpBrowser.ContainsText("Microsoft Corporation"));                
            } 
        }
```

When I invoke the service through the browser, the results are displayed but when watin runs through the same test, the results page has a 500 server error.

Any help appreciated please.

Comment: Is there any reason why you use waitn instead of calling the webservice through a autogenereated webservice-proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to test Web Service through WatiN?

There are better ways to do that: you should rather test your logic in unit / integration tests. Those tests will execute much faster than WatiN.

The HTTP 500 is returned by your web service - there is probably an exception being thrown from your code - check your logs or attach a debugger.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.

I already have unit tests for the web services but i'm currently playing with watin. Our page uses a lot of jquery to make calls to web services and I wanted to see if I could use watin to invoke a web service and check the xml returned.

There's no exception being thrown and there's nothing in the logs. It just fails.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jakub, using WatiN to test web services doesn't seem like a good idea.  You should consume the web service using Visual Studio, which will create a class for you.  You can call the web service via the generated class and check the result.